# Jquery-ползунок с маркером

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Подскажите, как добавить маркер к jquery.slider ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. там где надпись 50км, как можно добавить этот блок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов решения на основе [документации](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle), только нормально стилями подправить.

```js
$(function() {
  var handle = $("#custom-handle .value-output");
  $("#slider").slider({
    create: function() {
      handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      handle.text(ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#custom-handle {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.6em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.8em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  position: relative;
}

.value-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: -4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  right: -13px;
  color: #000000;
}

.value-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 20px;
  top: -16px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"><span class="value-wrapper"><span class="value-output"></span> км/ч</span>
  </div>
</div>
```